# Tabulator get data from table but in array

Tags: javascript, sorting, tabulator

I am using vuejs to get the data from table as shown in the image below ["1848"],["1796"], etc... But the data is not in array. I need the data to be in array to pass it to the php as my query will be like this

```
"SELECT * FROM bp.writer WHERE WPNo IN (?)"
```

[image: console log]

Here is my original code;

```
 let tableEntry = this.tableEntry.getRows(); 
    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tableEntry.length; i++) { 

        var obj = [tableEntry[i]._row.data["WPNo"]];
        //obj["WPNo"] = tableEntry[i]._row.data["WPNo"]; 

        console.log(obj) 
    }  
    //console.log(this.paymenttype) 

      window.open( axios.defaults.baseURL + "/pdf/bookpayment/print.php?Token=" +
                this.$store.getters.objUser.Token +
                "&UserID=" + this.$store.getters.objUser.UserID + 
                "&WPNo=" +  obj +  //need to pass in array
                "&Action=Print",
                "_blank");
```

What method or function should I use to convert the result in an array?

Comment: Post the actual working code or what you want to achieve and where you are stuck before you start getting downvoted this doesn't make any sense to a 3rd person

Comment: What is tableEntry then?

Comment: @Jalil tableEntry display the records

Comment: But if you are calling `tableEntry[i]` it means it is already an array.

Comment: Shouldn't the console.log supposedly shows like this -> for example _(3) ["1848","1796","1793"]_ not 1-by-1? @Jalil

Comment: No, because you are console.loggin `_row.data["WPNo"]]` in every tableEntry object. You never print the whole object

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
let tableEntry = this.tableEntry.getRows(); 
var array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < tableEntry.length; i++) { 

    var obj = [tableEntry[i]._row.data["WPNo"]];
    //obj["WPNo"] = tableEntry[i]._row.data["WPNo"]; 
    array.push(obj); //saves object into array

    console.log(obj) 
}  
//console.log(this.paymenttype) 

  window.open( axios.defaults.baseURL + "/pdf/bookpayment/print.php?Token=" +
            this.$store.getters.objUser.Token +
            "&UserID=" + this.$store.getters.objUser.UserID + 
            "&WPNo=" +  array +  //pass array
            "&Action=Print",
            "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

The question above is of very low quality, there is no tabledata nothing

The answer to your question **Tabulator get data from table but in array** http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/components#component-row

```
var rowData = row.getData();
```

```js
const tabledata1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli ",
    money: "0",
    col: "red",
    dob: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary ",
    money: "0",
    col: "blue",
    dob: "14/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Christine ",
    money: "0",
    col: "green",
    dob: "22/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brendon ",
    money: "0",
    col: "orange",
    dob: "01/08/1980"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Margret ",
    money: "0",
    col: "yellow",
    dob: "31/01/1999"
  },
];


const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
  data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
  layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  autoColumns: true
});
const removeArrow = function() {
  console.log(table.getData());
}


$('#removeArrow').click(function() {
  removeArrow();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>

  <button id="removeArrow">Get Data in console</button>



</body>

</html>
```